# I override an property's setter in subclass，but when I call it at superclass's init method, why the subclass's method response?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, overriding

When I code this:

```
//Father.m
@implementation Father

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = @"super class";

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    _name = [name copy];
    NSLog(@"super class");
}
@end
```

and in the subclass 'Son' I override the method 'setName:':

```
@synthesize name = _name;
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = @"sub class";

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    _name = [name copy];
    NSLog(@"sub class");
}
```

When I call this:

```
Son *s = [[Son alloc] init];
```

It prints this:

```
sub class
sub class
```

Why not:

```
super class
sub class
```

Who can explain why it called subclass's setter twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Son` calls `self = [super init]` at `- init`, that will calls Father's `init` method, but in `Father`'s `- init` method, `self` represents the time of `Son` , because `super` is just a keyword for the compiler. In the runtime phase, it is actually a message sent by the `objc_msgSendSuper` function, `objc_msgSendSuper` is a structure, which first parameter is `objc_super` structure pointer, inside the structure, first member is `receiver`, it stands `Son`.

```
struct objc_super {     
id receiver;
Class super_class;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.That means ' self ' is equal to ' super ' in ’msgSend‘，so all of this can be explained.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `self.name = @"super class"` in the `Father` class calls the `setName` setter implemented by the `Son` class, because `Son` overrides it. So it jumps back to the inheriting class. That is the benefit of inheritance. If you want to keep things separate, don't use inheritance.

Note: You can still access `setName` implemented in `Father` by calling `[super setName:]` from `Son`. Though, if you would use this in the initializer of `Father` it would try to access the superclass of Father which is probably `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

It prints

```
sub class
sub class
```

Because when you enter Father's init, `self` is of type `Son`, thus the call on `self.name` will call the setter on `Son` and not father. So, the setter on `Father` is never called. You can check this by modifying your init on `Father` to:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
        self.name = @"super class";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you'll see that `self` is actually a `Son` and not a `Father`